# I want to use grunt-mocha in my projects as the test framework

Tags: mocha.js

I have run `npm install -D grunt-mocha` to in stall `grunt-mocha`.

And I use `load-grunt-config` in my project.

So my mocha.js as follows:

```
`module.exports={
    test:{
        src:["tests/*.js"]
    }
};`
```

and my 'tests/test.js' as follows:

```
`var test = require('unit.js');
    describe('learning by the example.', function(){
    it('example variable', function(done){
        var example = "hello world.";
        test
            .string(example)
                .startsWith('hello')
                .match(/[a-z]/);
        });
    });`
```

An error

> Warning: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing Mocha run()
>   call.

is emitted  when I run `grunt mocha`.

Comment: It works well when I run `node_modules/grunt-mocha/bin/mocha tests/test.js -R spec`.

Comment: I solve my problem, I should use `grunt-mocha-test` plugin.
I chage `tests/mocha.js` -> `test/mochaTest.js`, and install `grunt-mocha-test` with `npm install grunt-mocha-test --save-dev`.